# Epson Print Admin

Tags: printing, epson

At my work place, printing is managed through the Epson Print Admin system. All documents are sent to one big queue and can then be printed at whichever printer is closer to you, after authentication with your personal badge (every printer has a card reader).
Is there a way to install and set up Epson Print Admin (or an equivalent system) on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.
  
You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.
  
From the command line, 

`lpstat -t`
  
will show the total state of the printing system.

Comment: I can see all printers in cups, bu the point is that with the epson print admin the jobs should not go to any particular printer but to a general queue that I don't see.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].